# How to set a maximum execution time for a c program?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and have no idea how to actually do it. I'm currently studying recursion on the programming course.

I need to make a program to list the maximum amount of numbers it can in 60 seconds of execution time.

Online the results are about measuring the execution time. My idea is to use the measurement of time to stop the counting part of the program, but again, I don't know how to do it.

I'm sorry for the simple/easy/school-related question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Begin to get the time when the program starts. Then each recursive call, or each iteration, get the current time and compare to the initial start time. If the difference is larger than larger or equal to `60` seconds then stop iterating or recursing, and let the program exit.

Comment: With that said, running a recursive function will most likely result in a stack overflow within a couple of seconds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it depends, the Ackermann function is reavily recursive and very long to compute if done naively, but the recursion depth is never very deep.

Comment: Use the [`time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time)  function to get the currrent time.

Comment: There are platform specific mechanisms for this sort of thing.  Try `man setitimer`